# Ubuntu internal error /bin/dash

Tags: 14.04, dash-shell

I am getting this error every time I boot into Ubuntu.

> "Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error"

I am suspecting it to cause an annoying **hanging of terminal applications 
when executing scripts** which often leads to system freezing.

By the way the script in question shebanged with:

> "#!/bin/**b**ash"

Any hint?

[image]

Comment: If you can get into a terminal session (either via the GUI or Ctrl+Alt+F1), run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dash`. If that command fails (as in segfaults), you'll need to use a Live CD/USB, chroot in, and then issue that command.

Comment: Run "sudo apt-get install --reinstall dash", but still the same error appears after reboot.

Comment: What are the outputs of `readlink -f /bin/bash` and `readlink -f $(which bash)`?

Comment: Both give "/bin/bash"

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt boot repair, but it might not fix your problem

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Do those 3 and select recommended repair, then reboot.
Open a terminal and

```
  sudo apt-get purge build-essential
  sudo apt-get update
```

Reboot. Terminal Again

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: David doesn't seem to affect the issue.

Comment: @AJN Okay, then like I said, I have no clue.